# BlackBerry programing - create borderless popup screen

Tags: java, blackberry, popup, screen

Do you know how to create borderless popup screen within Blackberry app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PopupScreen popup = new PopupScreen(new VerticalFieldManager());
popup.add(new LabelField("Hello!"));
Border border = BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(
        new XYEdges(), Border.STYLE_TRANSPARENT);
popup.setBorder(border);
```

Comment: When I set a background image for this new popup screen, I still can see a thin black border surrounding the popup screen. Do you know how to get rid of it also? Thank you.