# How to make Main Screen transparent in BlackBerry?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, java-me

I want to create an application in which I want to get a dialog when some event occurs. I am able to get the Dialog but behind that I am getting a white screen. I don't want that screen. Is there any way to make that screen transparent?

```
public final class LoadingPopupScreen extends PopupScreen
{
    Background  background;
    HorizontalFieldManager hfm;
    int width;
    int height;
    public LoadingPopupScreen( int width, int height)
    {  
        super(new VerticalFieldManager());
        background = BackgroundFactory.createLinearGradientBackground(Color.ROYALBLUE, Color.BLACK, Color.ROYALBLUE, Color.BLACK);
        setBackground(background);
        add(new LabelField("ROAMING"));
        add(new SeparatorField());
        add(new SeparatorField());
        hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("splash.png");
        BitmapField  bit= new BitmapField(bitmap);
        hfm.add(bit);
        hfm.add(new LabelField("want to check In Roaming or not?"));
        add(hfm);
        hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.FIELD_HCENTER);
        ButtonField ok = new ButtonField("OK", HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);
        ButtonField cancel = new ButtonField("CANCEL", HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);
        hfm.add(ok);
        hfm.add(cancel);
        add(hfm);
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to background you have to set borders to empty

Comment: Thanks but can u plz give me some code to implement this..

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216382/blackberry-programing-create-borderless-popup-screen

Comment: Sir, i don't want to transparent Border, i want that the only pop up screen will appear on the screen but i am getting white screen on the back of pop up screen..

Comment: i want on background Menu Screen of Mobile will show in which messages, contacts icons are there. that what i want, Sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done it using:

```
Ui.getUiEngine().pushGlobalScreen(new LoadingPopupScreen(300,300), 0, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
```